# error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

vengo con este error:

error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

el error esta al usar las funciones atoi() y atof() en la cadena de caracteres.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

void PedirDatos();
void SepararEntero(char numeroChar);

int main(){
    char numeroChar[20];

    PedirDatos();
    SepararEntero(char numeroChar);

    return 0;
}

void PedirDatos(){
    cout<<"Digite un numero decimal: ";
    cin.getline(numeroChar,20,'\n');
}

void SepararEntero(char numeroChar){
    int numero;
    float numeroDecimal;
    float resultado;

    numero=atoi(numeroChar);
    numeroDecimal=atof(numeroChar);

    resultado=numeroDecimal-numero;

    cout<<"La parte decimal del numero es: "<<resultado<<endl;
}
```

He hecho pruebas con solo la funcion atoi() y atof() y en todas las pruebas que hago el codigo compila sin problemas.

la prueba es:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char numChar[]={"123.456"};
    int num;
    float num2;

    num=atoi(numChar);
    num2=atof(numChar);

    cout<<num<<endl;
    cout<<num2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output de Prueba.cpp:
123
123.456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Llamadas incorrectas**

Tienes que distinguir entre declaración de funciones y su invocación.

Al declarar una variable tienes que indicar de qué tipo son los parámetros que recibe. De la misma forma es aquí donde se indica si una función devuelve o no algún tipo de dato:

```
void SepararEntero(char numeroChar);
```

Al invocar la función no hace falta repetir de qué tipo son los parámetros. Eso ya lo sabe el compilador. Lo que haces en este punto es facilitarle los valores para que la función se pueda ejecutar correctamente:

```
// Bien
char numeroChar = 'c';
SepararEntero(numeroChar);

// Mal
char numeroChar = 'c';
SepararEntero(char numeroChar);
```

**2. Coherencia de tipos**

No es lo mismo una piedra que un plátano y, de la misma manera, no es lo mismo un *char* y un array de *char*:

```
char numeroChar[20];
SepararEntero(numeroChar);
```

Tu has indicado en la declaración de `Separarentero` que recibe un `char` ... y le estás pasando (una vez corregido el error indicado en el punto anterior), un `char`.

Entiendo que tu intención aquí es trabajar con `char*`, no con `char`, así que tienes que actualizar la función `SepararEntero`:

```
void SepararEntero(char* numeroChar)
{
    // ...
}
```

La implementación, en teoría, ahora sí sería correcta, ya que `atoi` y `atof` esperan un array de *char*, no un *char* suelto.

**3. Variables inexistentes**

Si revisas la función `PedirDatos`, verás que, para esta función, no existe ninguna variable llamada `numeroChar`, no la declaras, y, sin embargo, si la usas:

```
void PedirDatos(){
    // Declaración ¿¿??

    cout<<"Digite un numero decimal: ";
    cin.getline(numeroChar,20,'\n'); // <<--- Uso
}
```

Dado que `numeroChar` hemos quedado en que es un array, y teniendo en cuenta que los arrays decaen a punteros (sufren una conversión implícita), podemos aprovecharnos de las propiedades de los punteros para actualizar la variable que nos interesa, que es la que se usa para invocar a la función:

```
void PedirDatos(char * numeroChar){ // <<--- numeroChar aquí es un puntero
    cout<<"Digite un numero decimal: ";
    cin.getline(numeroChar,20,'\n');
}
```

Y, claro, ahora hay que actualizar la invocación de dicha función:

```
int main(){
    char numeroChar[20];

    PedirDatos(numeroChar);
    SepararEntero(char numeroChar);

    return 0;
}
```

Claro que ya que tienes el número en un array de caracteres, separar la parte entera de la decimal habría sido más sencillo:

```
void SepararEntero(char const * numeroChar)
{
    char const* ptr = numeroChar + 1;
    while( *(ptr-1) !='.' && *ptr !='\0' ) ptr++;

    std::cout << "Parte decimal: " << (*ptr ? ptr : "0") << '\n';
}
```

Explicación:

Suponte que partes de un array de caracteres tal que:

```
1 2 3 4 5 . 6 7 8 \0
```

Lo que hace el `while` es avanzar el puntero por dicha cadena hasta posicionarse justo después del separador de decimales:

```
1 2 3 4 5 . 6 7 8 \0
            ^
            ptr
```

Después se comprueba si `ptr` apunta al final de la cadena o no. Si apunta al final de la cadena imprimirá un 0 y, si no, imprimirá la parte decimal del número.

Nota 1: El operador `?` es el condicional terciario y su forma es la siguiente:

```
[condicion] ? [operación si condicion cierta] : [operacion si condicion falsa];
```

Nota 2: La función recibe un puntero constante porque la misma no necesita modificar la cadena `numeroChar`.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un error de linkeo en `char numeroChar[20];`
la variable `numeroChar` no puede ser modificada en

```
void PedirDatos(){
    cout<<"Digite un numero decimal: ";
    cin.getline(numeroChar,20,'\n');
}
```

Noobstante el siguiente codigo te puede servir

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

void PedirDatos(char numeroChar[]);
void SepararEntero(char numeroChar[]);

int main(){

    char numeroChar[20];
    PedirDatos(numeroChar);
    SepararEntero(numeroChar);

    return 0;
}

void PedirDatos(char numeroChar[]){
    cout<<"Digite un numero decimal: ";
    cin.getline(numeroChar,20,'\n');
}

void SepararEntero(char numeroChar[]){
    int numero;
    double numeroDecimal;
    double resultado;

    numero=atoi(numeroChar);
    numeroDecimal=atof(numeroChar);

    resultado=numeroDecimal-numero;

    cout<<"La parte decimal del numero es: "<<resultado<<endl;
}
```

*cambie **double** por **float** para la precision*