# Deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c, warnings, char

Tengo una duda, me han pedido este programa por parte de la escuela pero a la hora de compilar me marca esta advertencia así como me muestra en pantalla un "(null)" cuando ejecuto el programa.

Aquí el código.

```
int leeValido(char letrero[30]);
int factorial(int numero);
float gradosRad(int x);
float calculaSerie(int x, int n);
void  imprimeResultados(int x, int n, float resultado);

int main()
{
    int numero, x, n;
    float resultado;
    char letrero[30];
    system("color 03");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    
    x = leeValido("\nPara x: ");
    n = leeValido("\nNúmero de iteraciones: ");
    resultado = calculaSerie(x,n);
    imprimeResultados(x, n, resultado);

    return 0;
}

int leeValido(char letrero[30])
{
    int numero;
    
    do
    {
        printf("%s", letrero[30]);
        scanf("%d", &numero);
    } while ((numero < 1) || (numero-numero > 0)); //no va a dejar de preguntar hasta que sea positivo
    
    return numero;
}
```

He intentado mandarla como variables separadas pero me aparecen más errores cuando lo intento.

Comment: segun entendi lo que quieres es pasar a una funcion una cadena de caracteres para que este se muestre por pantalla?

Comment: Si, en sí debo de pintar lo que le estoy enviando a la función `leeValido( );`.
He intentado declarar las dos cadenas como cadenas independientes para así enviarlas a la función pero no funciona y genera más errores.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char\*’ \[-fpermissive\]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428699/error-invalid-conversion-from-char-to-const-char-fpermissive)

Comment: Claro que sí, muchas gracias! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("%s", letrero[30]);
```

Aquí tienes un problema y es qué no estás pasando un array, si no que estás pasando el elemento 31 del array letrero, si quieres pasar la `string` constante que utilizas en tu código te recomiendo que la pases como una string de c (por su referencia, en este caso el puntero a su primer elemento):

```
printf("%s", letrero);
```

De paso te recomiendo pasar de igual manera la `string` a tu función y declararla como:

```
int leeValido(char * letrero);
```

Answer (score 0):

en lo que estas fallando es que estas pasando un mensaje a la funcion como si fuera un string pero tu funcion pide un solo caracter char, debes pasar el argumento char como un arreglo y usar la sentensia strcpy(destino,origen);

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void laeer(char text[]){
    char as[30];
    strcpy(as,text);
    printf("%s",as);
}

int main(){
    char texto1[]="\nPara x: ";
    char texto2[]="\nNumero de iteraciones: ";
    laeer(texto1);
}
```

Haci es como debes hacer tu función y mensajes.

Comment: Esta solución también funciona, sin embargo, creo que es un desperdicio de memoria copiar la string para imprimirla, especialmente al ser una string constate. Puedes imprimirla directamente.